# spring security - remember-me with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, cookies, remember-me

I'm using spring (security) for a REST webservice and remember-me to keep my users logged in without the need to relogin too often.

The problem is, if the jsession expires, remember-me seems to need a dedicated single synchronous request to get a new jsession-cookie for future requests.

**Is there a good alternative or modification to remember-me that handles parallel requests well?**

Alternatively, I had the idea to send a custom error code "on cookietheft". Whenever the client receives this code, it could wait some seconds to let the first request finish. Then issue the other requests again with the new cookie. But the problem on this **workaround** is, that only the first failed request is raising the "cookietheft". All other ajax calls return with `401`. Is there a way to detect those calls also in relation to the "cookietheft" so I can return the same special statuscode?